# Setting current_timestamp() with different timezones in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table where I have two DATETIME columns, one for America/NEW_YORK timezone and other Pakistan. I want to know if there is a why where I can set up default timezone for both, like I set up current_timestamp(), For example: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + 9;`  but I can give it timezones without changing global timezone. Here is the structure of my table:
[image]

Comment: no you can't do that in any rdms afaik

Comment: default timezone is already set, as soon as you start your database.

Comment: use  a neutral time zone and add the hours, in your select, as you know which column you want#

Comment: @nbk I wanted to find an implementation in mySQL, but instead I will enter date using PHP and make sure no excption occurs. Hope that works

Comment: Remove CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from column if you are going to set a timezone different than your database's

Comment: I think the correct approach is to store the datetime in UTC, then convert it when you want to present it to the user

Comment: @IndraKumarS I did that to eloborate using the picture but otherwise now, I have removed timestamp

Comment: @JeffUK I am keeping two seperate dates because in my Project sceanario, too many reports are needed for same users, some for US and other with PK timezone, and converting them on so many reports and pages everytime feel like a daunting task.

Comment: @AunZaidi that's nothing compared to when you get a new time zone for one of your reports (US has several) and have to go back and add that datetime to ever column in your table, or do the conversion in the report anyway. How will daylight saving time need to be taken into acocunt? etc. etc.

Comment: @JeffUK yes, you make good points. I am infact going to do so, change set timezone from UTC to whatever requried, as I should be following best practices. For now, I was using PHP date function and that does take care of DTS. Here's part of my code. `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $usa_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`Thanks for advice, as I am going to use this now.